# Change WordPress Resource URL

Tags: theme-development, cdn

I have recently finished developing my latest WordPress theme for my own site and as usual I was going to use maxcdn and w3tc to make it faster!

However my Hosting company have started up their own cdn service and I have got 3 months free to test it out! However it is not as easy to set up as Maxcdn and have been told that I need to change the resource url to use cdn url and serve my images, css and js files.

I have added all my css and js files in my function.php file like so...

```
wp_enqueue_style('BrumWebEngineer-style', get_stylesheet_uri());
wp_enqueue_style('BrumWebEngineer-core', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/core.css');
```

Naturally I cannot replace the get_template_diretory_uri with the cdn url so am wondering how I can go about this.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To dinamically change the stylesheet and template URI you can use `stylesheet_uri` filter and `template_directory_uri` filter.

For example:

```
add_filter( 'stylesheet_uri', function( $stylesheet_uri ) {

    $stylesheet_uri = 'your new stylesheet URI here';

    return $stylesheet_uri;

} );
```

But, as you are using W3TC, you can configure that change in the plugin itself (Generic Mirror and Self-hosted CDN options), even you can configure pushing files automatically if the CDN service support it.

Comment: Agreed your's is a lot more complete! thats an awesome idea! I may just use that to test it!

Answer (score 1):

I Finally figure it out!

By selecting the General settings under W3TC I selected CDN and CDN Type I then selected Generic Mirror.

I then clicked on the CDN link under performance and was able to add my CDN URL and test the mirror!
Pretty simple when you know how!

Comment: You answered your question just at the same than me. Upvote your answer but I think mine is more complete.